# Enumerar Líneas de TextBox y mostrarlo en otro TextBox en C#

Tags: c#

Hola muy buenas ¿alguien sabe como enumerar las lineas de un TextBox1 y mostrar el numero de lineas desde 0 a n en otro textBox?, lo que tengo pensado es con la propiedad de lines contar el numero de lineas del Texbox1 y después imprimir con un ciclo en el textBox2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado esto en codigo.

```
private void textBox1_MultilineChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //no entra al for porque el textbox2 no tiene datos, esta vacio
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox2.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            textBox2.Lines[i] = (i+1).ToString();
        }
    }
```

pero no funciona porque el texbox2 no tiene datos después asignarle un arreglo vacío con tamaño de lines del texbox1 pero tampoco funciona ya que no escribe nada.

```
private void textBox1_MultilineChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Lines = new string[textBox1.Lines.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox2.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            textBox2.Lines[i] = (i+1).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Y porque quiere complicarse la vida? Porque no usa un listbox o un datagridview simplemente ?

Comment: wpf o winforms o uwp o sobre que cosa?

Comment: sobre winForms.

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución es no tratar de obtener el número de líneas de la forma en que lo esta intentando si no más bien aprovechar el evento  TextChanged de un textBox y de esta forma cada vez que se teclee en el mismo en una variable podría ir almacenando en tiempo real la cantidad de líneas. Ej :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private int Lineas ;

    private int Aux ;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Lineas = 0;Aux = 0;
    }

   

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Lineas = textBox1.Lines.Length + 1;

        if (Lineas > Aux || Lineas < Aux)//cambiaron las líneas
        {
            textBox2.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i < Lineas; i++)
            {
                textBox2.Text += "" + i + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            Aux = Lineas;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: si puede servir pero el problema es que si lo pongo en un timer la funcion de llenar el textbox izquierdo donde debe ir la secuencia de (1 hasta N) se repetirá todo el tiempo y lo encimara el objetivo es que en el textbox izquierdo solo imprima (1,2,3,4,5,6,n) dependiendo de las líneas que se han escrito en el textbox derecho si se borra una linea en el derecho el textbox izquierdo se debe actualizar etc..

Comment: Pruebe con los nuevos cambios que hice. Adjunte la clase completa